# AngularJS - Unit Test Directive with jquery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.directive('newDirective', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
            console.log("newDirective Content:"+$("#sub").html());
        }
    };
}]);
```

I tried to do unit test with this:

```
describe('newDirective Test',function(){
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    it('Temporary test jquery function', inject(function($compile,$rootScope) {
        var element = $compile('<div new-directive><div id="sub">abc</div></div>')($rootScope);
    }));
});
```

When I run the directive normally, I get the output `newDirective Content:abc`. But when I run unit test, I get log output `newDirective Content:undefined`.

How can I get jquery function to work in unit test?

Comment: Do anyone knows how to get this done? This is very important for me to continue with unit test. TQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you (if you have control) that you don't use jQuery get the html within

```
<div id="sub">abc</div>
```

and instead use [jQlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to search the DOM.

```
testApp.directive('newDirective', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
            console.log("newDirective Content:"+element.find('#sub').html());
        }
    };
}]);
```

You also may then wish to re-factor your spec so that the compilation of the html takes place outside the it function - jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/9o71q3k4/1/).

```
describe('newDirective Test',function(){
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));

    var element, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<div new-directive><div id="sub">abc</div></div>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it("should contain a div tag", function() {
        expect(element.find('div').length).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 8):

If really want to use jQuery function in directive, this is how it can be done in unit test:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var element = angular.element('<div new-directive><div id="sub">abc</div></div>');
element.appendTo(document.body);
element = $compile(element)(scope);
```

By adding `element.appendTo(document.body);`, you will get jQuery function work in unit test.

Comment: Very clever.  Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element as the second argument:

`$('#your-id', element);`

Or you can just pass the element as the `$()` argument and use other methods:

`$(element).find('#your-id');`